# PHP PDO Query - Exception performing SQLSTATE[IMSSP] This function is not implemented by this driver

Tags: php, pdo

Hoping someone can provide some insight to this - wasn't able to find much on Google referencing the error I'm getting.

I have a simple PHP page that has some links on it that should open up Skype For Business chat windows with members that are in the group of the link that is clicked. (IE: a link is clicked for a specific team and a database query finds the users and launches Skype window like

```
 <a href=”sip:person@website.com″></a>
```

Application flow is as follows :

index.php -- navbar link

```
  <li><a href="#" id="Team1" onclick="return 
          loadChatGroup(this.id)">Team1</a></li>
```

calls this

```
            function loadChatGroup(t) {
            console.log(t);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'components/chat/chatLoader.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: "text",
                data: 'team=' + t
            });
               return false;
        }
```

chatLoader.php

```
//Load all our project classes here 
<?php include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/myApp/includes/app.php"; 

if (isset($_POST['team'])){
$conn = new Connection();
$pdo = $conn->DBH;

$chats = new Chat($pdo);
$team = $_POST['team'];
$getMembers = $chats->getChatMembers($team);


foreach ($getMembers as $member){
    echo "<a href='$member'></a>";
}
}
?>
```

chat.php

```
<?php
  class Chat
{
private $conn;

public function __construct($pdo)
{
    $this->conn = $pdo;
}



public function getChatMembers($data)

{

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT SIP FROM test.chats WHERE 
    Group_Name = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param(1, $data);
    $stmt->execute();
    $members = $stmt->fetchAll();
    return $members; 

   }
}
```

I am able to verify the connection is established by and class instantiated fine by print_r on my $pdo and $chat variables.

When the query is called it returns " Exception performing SQLSTATE[IMSSP] This function is not implemented by this driver "

I have other classes and queries that run fine and this error seems to come up regardless of the sql statement I try to run from my chat class.

Not sure where to go from here...

Comment: `bind_param()` is mysqli, not PDO - there it would be `bindValue()`.

Comment: actually bindParam() fixed the issue. such a silly mistake. thank you!